# iAd * InMobi ads are failing to return via AdWhirl. But why?

Tags: ios-simulator, iad, adwhirl

I'm just getting started with AdWhirl (though i'v ebeen using iAds for a while).
I added iAd and InMobi support, as well as In-House ads.

I have an NSLog on the adWhirlDidFailToReceiveAd delegate method.
Here i can see that it fails twice (for iAds and InMobi requests).
However AdWhirl does give me my In-House ad correctly.

NOTE: I am calling this from the simulator.
Am I getting a fail-to-receive message because iAds and InMobi are not supported on the simulator?

Also, if I run this from my device, will i be able to see the various Ads?

Please confirm or deny or provide any other insight.
Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***

After my InMobi account/ad was "Activated" i am now seeing the Ad come in for InMobi.
However, i am still getting a failed-to-receive message for Apple's iAds. Again, this is via simulator. Not sure about device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you face any issues integrating with InMobi, please email helpdesk@inmobi.com and they will revert to you at the earlier.

(Full Disclosure: I work with InMobi in the Global Operations Team in supporting publisher integration)